# Having trouble with ul in firefox and others

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, html-lists

I cannot seem to get my menu items to be clickable...they work in IE, but not Firefox or Chrome. I can also get them to work on my iPad in Chrome and Safari, but not when I hold the iPad in landscape mode. Very weird.

HTML:

```
<div id="options" class="clearfix">
<ul id="filters" class="option-set clearfix" data-option-key="filter">
<li><a href="#filter" data-option-value="*" class="selected">All</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".tech">Tech</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".social">Social</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".health">Health</a></li>  
</ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#options ul {
  list-style: none outside none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#options li {
  display: inline;
}
#options li a {
    color:#666666;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 34px;
}
#options li a:hover {
    color:#3B5998;
}
#options li a:active {
    color:#3B5998;
}
#options li a.selected {
    color:#3B5998;
}
```

Any help would be great, I am not the best at HTML and CSS so I appreciate any insight.

My site is www.pinstart.us

Cheers.

Comment: I don't think this is related to the CSS you're using. What plugin are you using to handle the smooth-scrolling to elements? I suspect that is the culprit here - not the CSS.

Comment: Your logo looks awfully similar to another company's logo.

Comment: BenM, I'm not even sure to be honest. Its a template I'm using, so I didn't write a lot of the code...I'll keep troubleshooting, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ".navbar-fixed-top" div is overlapping the "#option" bar !

you can verify this by setting:

```
.navbar-fixed-top{
z-index: -5;
}
```

**edit:** this wont ruin the site looks.

```
#options{
position:relative;
z-index: 9999;
}
```

hope this points you on the right direction !

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine for me but you could try making your 'a' tags display: inline-block

```
#options li a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You do mean the menu at the top-right of your page don't you? I've tested it in Firefox, Chrome and IE and I can click on the links fine. The layout of your site is way off in general in IE 7/8 btw.

Comment: No the one under Startups....All, Tech, Social, Health...fixed now anyways! Now on to trying to make it look good in IE...blargh. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing your

```
<a href...>
```

tags outside of your

```
<li>
```

tags instead of inside them? I know that sometimes this makes a difference for me.

Comment: That would make a difference by making the HTML not be valid.

Comment: Thanks for providing an example of badly written, invalid html with regards to the UL element. Run your website through this HTML validator so you can see for yourself: http://validator.w3.org You may also want to consider checking your website in Internet Explorer too as it has one or two layout issues which could probably be addressed by adding the HTML5 shiv file and a CSS reset file.

Comment: Fascinating. I will have to revise that particular method of doing things. Thanks.